# keeping sessions alive over subdomains

Tags: php

I have a subdomain that users log into `(my.domain-uk.net)` which stores a session variable to say that the user is logged in. The variable looks like:

```
$_SESSION["domain-uk.net"]["customer_loggedin"] = 'yes';
```

when i echo this on any page in the `my.` subdomain it displays `'yes'` but as soon as i go back to the main domain `(domain-uk.net)` and echo the variable it doesn't show anything

i have `session_start();` on every page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .htaccess you can set your session cookie domain to the base.

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".domain-uk.net"
```

You can also do this inside of your application:

```
<?php 
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain-uk.net'); 
session_start(); 
?>
```

Comment: using that i get an Internal Server Error

Comment: second option still doesn't save sessions

Comment: Your .htaccess configuration may be limited.  Try the second option I added.

Comment: tried that one, but still not saving sessions

Comment: have also just tried clearing cache and cookies and logging in again

Comment: Can you post your Cookie headers from the subdomain and main domain?

Comment: If you use Firebug or the Chrome debugger they will be under the 'Net' tab in the Request and Response headers.

Comment: Yes, in Chrome debugger it is 'Network' then select your .php file and the headers are under 'Headers' you will find cookie.  In Firebug it's the 'Net' tab then select your .php file and Headers are under Headers.  Post the Cookie: header from the request and response.

Comment: there is nothing listed there, not .php files or anything ?

Comment: You will need to reload the php page with the Network tab open

Comment: ok here is index.php headers (index.php page for my.domain-uk.net/index.php) - http://pastebin.com/zvDczUfb

Comment: That looks OK, how about under Resources->Cookies->{site}.  What are the session cookie settings.  Specifically, what is the domain and path for the PHPSESSID?